# How to add a close button to this JavaScript in aframe

Tags: javascript, aframe

Essentially I have a modal window in aframe that I am trying to add a close button to via javascript but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Link to the project below:

https://andrewmc1994.github.io/Image-Link-Test/

If you highlight the compass icon you will see what I mean.

This is for a university project, i've looked at various methods online but none of them seem to work so that's why I have come here.

```
        <a-entity ui-modal="triggerElement:#selection;" visible="false">

         <a-image src="#submenu" scale="3.5 3.5 0" position="0 -0.25 2" src-fit></a-image>

            <a-image position="-1 -0.25 2.1" class="clickable" src="#tqicon" scale="0.7 0.7 0" link="href:location1.html; on: click; visualAspectEnabled: false" src-fit></a-image>

             <a-image position="0 -0.25 2.1" class="clickable" src="#acicon" scale="0.7 0.7 0" link="href:location3.html; on: click; visualAspectEnabled: false" src-fit></a-image>

             <a-image position="1 -0.25 2.1" class="clickable" src="#bchicon" scale="0.7 0.7 0" link="href:location2.html; on: click; visualAspectEnabled: false" src-fit></a-image>

            <a-image position="1.4 0 2.1" class="clickable" src="#close" scale="0.1 0.1 0" id="close" src-fit></a-image>

        </a-entity>
```

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    /**
     * UI modal component for A-Frame.
     */

    if (typeof AFRAME === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('Component attempted to register before AFRAME was available.');
    }

    AFRAME.registerComponent('ui-modal', {

        schema: {
            trigger: {
                default: 'click'
            },
            triggerElement: {
              default: '',
            },
            zpos: {
                default: -4
            }
        },

        init: function() { 

            document.querySelector(this.data.triggerElement).addEventListener(this.data.trigger, this.eventHandler.bind(this));

            this.cameraEl = document.querySelector('a-entity[camera]');

            this.yaxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            this.zaxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

            this.pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
            this.el.object3D.position.set(0, this.cameraEl.object3D.getWorldPosition().y, this.data.zpos);

            this.el.sceneEl.object3D.add(this.pivot);
            this.pivot.add(this.el.object3D);

        },


        eventHandler: function(evt) {

            if (this.el.getAttribute('visible') === false) {

                var direction = this.zaxis.clone();
                direction.applyQuaternion(this.cameraEl.object3D.quaternion);
                var ycomponent = this.yaxis.clone().multiplyScalar(direction.dot(this.yaxis));
                direction.sub(ycomponent);
                direction.normalize();

                this.pivot.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(this.zaxis, direction);
                this.pivot.position.copy(this.cameraEl.object3D.getWorldPosition());

                this.el.setAttribute('visible', true);

            } else if (this.el.getAttribute('visible') === true) {

                this.el.setAttribute('visible', false);
            }

        },

        update: function (oldData) {},

        remove: function() {}

    });




/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

So the expected result is for the user to open the modal window and then have the ability to close it with a simple button.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cannot highlight the compass icon. your question is not clear - at least to me. consider to abstract your question to the very essential part...

Comment: @Axel This video showcases the issue, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3Yrz8eTJiA&feature=youtu.be I want to be able to close the popup with the X icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add any functionality to the existing close button. Your `eventHandler` already contains logic for showing / hiding the UI, so just add a listener to the close button:

```
let closeBtn = document.getElementById("close") one close button
closeBtn.addEventListener(this.data.trigger, this.eventHandler.bind(this))
```

When clicked - it will hide the UI.

However, there are more elements with the `ui-modal` component, and their `eventHandler` trigger the `setAttribute("visible", "")` part.

The easiest way to deal with this would be

```
closeBtn.addEventListener(this.data.trigger, e => {
  this.el.setAttribute("visible", "false")
})
```

let the close button hide the element, nothing more to be done here.

---

As for Axel's concerns, you don't really have to do much comparing. You can treat them as booleans:

This is valid:

```
if (this.el.getAttribute("visible") {
  // hide
} else {
  // show
}
```

as well as this:

```
// toggle visibility
this.el.setAttribute("visible", !this.el.getAttribute("visible")
```

You can check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/bhozx6va/3/) fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added in the code simply as:                                     
         <script>
        
        document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("close", eventHandler)
            
        </script> Is this correct? As it doesn't seem to be working. I have a close id on the a-image aswell. appreciate the help.

Comment: It has to be within the `init` function in the `ui-modal` component, let me know if it works. Btw I'm using the `id` in the `getElementById` :)

Comment: I have it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cz406osh/ I just seem to be getting a whitescreen however, do I have it set up correctly?

Comment: sorry, i've rushed a bit my anwser, check out the updated version. I thought the `bind` was made in another way. check out if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/y6r3ch24/) is working for you

Comment: Hi, thats great, thank you it does work and closes the box however I have two other popups on the same page which trigger when I close the first box. This video showcases what I mean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KX3f-urY2Y&feature=youtu.be. Anyone around this? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Zecele check out my update, let me know if its plausible

Comment: Sorted it, had to change closebtn to closing and it seems to work perfectly now, really appreciate your help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to debug your issue but there is one thing thats looking "not right" to me!

Your event handler validates `this.el.getAttribute('visible')` against `true` and `false` as booleans but `getAttribute` will always return a string (which would be `'true'` and `'false'` in this particular case) or `null` if the attribute does not exist.

So you should validate like this at the `eventHandler` part:

```
if ( this.el.getAttribute('visible') === 'false' ) { // validate against 'false' instead of false
    /* ... */
    this.el.setAttribute('visible', 'true'); // set to 'true' instead of true
} else if ( this.el.getAttribute('visible') === 'true' ) { // validate against 'true' instead of true
    /* ... */
    this.el.setAttribute('visible', 'false'); // set to 'false' instead of false
}
```

But after further inspection I noticed that actually the A-Frame(work) seems not to set elements attributeValue of attributeName `visible` to `"true"|"false"`.
Instead if an element is visible its set to `visible=""` and if its invisible its set to `visible="false"`. So only if this is true you should do it like this:

```
if ( this.el.getAttribute('visible') === 'false' ) { // validate against 'false' instead of false
    /* ... */
    this.el.setAttribute('visible', ''); // set to '' instead of true
} else if ( this.el.getAttribute('visible') === '' ) { // validate against '' instead of false
    /* ... */
    this.el.setAttribute('visible', 'false'); // set to 'false' instead of false
}
```